# C++ Console Conway's Game of Life very slow updates

Tags: c++, performance, conways-game-of-life

I am currently working on a console version of Conway's Game of Life in C++.

[Repo Link](https://github.com/Alex-Jay/GameOfLife/tree/test/GameOfLife)

The problem is that my Draw() method is drawing the next generation not as fast as possible.

I remember reading somewhere that using GotoXY is quite slow compared to getting the console buffer.

The problem is I don't have a single notion how to implement a console buffer to work with my code.

I'm not asking for you guys to do it, yet I just wanted for you to look at my Draw() and Update() method to see if I'm doing something scarily memory hogging.

My code probably isn't the best since I still "reasonably new" to C++ so keep that in mind before critiquing. :')

Cell Struct

```
struct Cell
{
int x, y; // Cell X, Y coordiantes
bool IsAlive; // Cell life state

string ToString()
{
    return "X: " + to_string(x) + "\tY" + to_string(y) + "\tAlive State: " + to_string(IsAlive);
}

void Die()
{
    IsAlive = false;
}

void Resurrect()
{
    IsAlive = true;
}
};
```

Update

```
void Update()
{
// Update Cells
CalculateNextGeneration(CellMap);
}
```

Draw

```
void Draw()
{
for (auto cell : CellMap) // Iterate through all cells in CellMap vector
{
    // Draw Cell if Alive
    // If a cell was alive upto 10th generation, display cell as '1'.
    if (cell.IsAlive)
        GotoXY(cell.x, cell.y, AliveCell);
    // If a cell is dead, display cell as ' '.
    else
        GotoXY(cell.x, cell.y, DeadCell);
}
}
```

CalculateNextGeneration

```
 /* 
TODO: Encapsulate IF Statements

Game Rules
1: Any Live Cell which has < 2 Live Neighbours, die [ Underpopulation ]
2: Any Live Cell which has 2 OR 3 Neighbours, live
3: Any Live Cell which has > 3 Neighbours, die [ Overpopulation ]
4: Any Dead Cell which has EXACTLY 3 Neighbours, resurrect [ Reporduciton ]

*/
void CalculateNextGeneration(vector<Cell> &map)
{
    for (auto& cell : map) // Iterate through all cells as references
    {
        if ((cell.IsAlive && GetAdjacentCellCount(cell, map) < 2) || (cell.IsAlive && GetAdjacentCellCount(cell, map) > 3)) // If current cell has < 2 neighbours OR current cell has > 3 neighbours, die [ Underpopulation & Overpopulation ] 
        {
            // Die
            cell.Die();
        }
        if (cell.IsAlive && GetAdjacentCellCount(cell, map) == 2 || GetAdjacentCellCount(cell, map) == 3) // If current cell has 2 OR 3 adjacent neighbours, live until next generation.
        {
            // Live Until Next Generation
        }
        if (!cell.IsAlive && GetAdjacentCellCount(cell, map) == 3) // If current cell has EXACTLY 3 adjacent neighbours, resurrect [ Reproduciton ]
        {
            // Resurrect
            cell.Resurrect();
        }
    }
}
```

GetAdjacentCellCount

```
/* Count Adjacent cells

Long version of counting adjacent cells.
TODO: Clean up code.

Example:

0 = Dead Cell
1 = Alive Cell
X = Current Cell

    1   0   1
    0   X   0
    1   1   0

Return would be 4 in this case. Since There are 4 alive cells surround the current cell (X).

The function doesn't consider the current cell's life state.

*/
int GetAdjacentCellCount(Cell &currentCell, vector<Cell> &map)
{
    int aliveCount = 0;

    int currentX = currentCell.x;
    int currentY = currentCell.y;

    vector<Cell> adjacentCells; // Create temporary vector with all adjacent cells

    adjacentCells.push_back(GetCellAtXY(currentX - 1, currentY - 1, map));  // - - // TOP LEFT CELL
    adjacentCells.push_back(GetCellAtXY(currentX, currentY - 1, map));      // 0 - // TOP MIDDLE CELL
    adjacentCells.push_back(GetCellAtXY(currentX + 1, currentY - 1, map));  // + - // TOP RIGHT CELL
    adjacentCells.push_back(GetCellAtXY(currentX + 1, currentY, map));      // + 0 // MIDDLE LEFT CELL
    adjacentCells.push_back(GetCellAtXY(currentX + 1, currentY + 1, map));  // + + // MIDDLE RIGHT CELL
    adjacentCells.push_back(GetCellAtXY(currentX, currentY + 1, map));      // 0 + // BOTTOM LEFT CELL
    adjacentCells.push_back(GetCellAtXY(currentX - 1, currentY + 1, map));  // - + // BOTTOM MIDDLE CELL
    adjacentCells.push_back(GetCellAtXY(currentX - 1, currentY, map));      // - - // BOTTOM RIGHT CELL

    for (auto adjCell : adjacentCells) // Iterate through all adjacent cells
    {
        if (adjCell.IsAlive == true) // Count how many are alive
            aliveCount++;
    }

    return aliveCount;
}
```

GetCellAtXY

```
Cell GetCellAtXY(int x, int y, vector<Cell> &map)
{
    Cell retrievedCell = { 0, 0, false }; // Create a default return cell

    for (auto cell : map) // Iterate through all cells in the map
    {
        if (cell.x == x && cell.y == y) // If Cell is found at coordinate X, Y
            retrievedCell = cell; // Set found Cell to return Cell
    }

    return retrievedCell;
}
```

Comment: It would be best if you included relevant method in the question rather than linking to external repo.

Comment: Also you may have better luck at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @orhtej2 is that a bit better?

Comment: CellMap could be a map instead of a vector, and could use its positional ID as it's key.  Then you could have cell lookups in O(1) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably gain a lot of time rewriting your `GetAdjacentCellCount` function:

```
if (GetCellAtXY(currentX - 1, currentY - 1, map)  // - - // TOP LEFT CELL
   aliveCount++;
if (GetCellAtXY(currentX, currentY - 1, map));    // 0 - // TOP MIDDLE CELL
   aliveCount++;
if (GetCellAtXY(currentX + 1, currentY - 1, map)  // + - // TOP RIGHT CELL
   aliveCount++;
if (GetCellAtXY(currentX + 1, currentY, map)      // + 0 // MIDDLE LEFT CELL
   aliveCount++;
if (GetCellAtXY(currentX + 1, currentY + 1, map)  // + + // MIDDLE RIGHT CELL
   aliveCount++;
if (GetCellAtXY(currentX, currentY + 1, map)      // 0 + // BOTTOM LEFT CELL
   aliveCount++;
if (GetCellAtXY(currentX - 1, currentY + 1, map)  // - + // BOTTOM MIDDLE CELL
   aliveCount++;
if (GetCellAtXY(currentX - 1, currentY, map)      // - - // BOTTOM RIGHT CELL
   aliveCount++;
```

Filling the vector using `push_back` causes several heap allocations to occur for every cell, at every iteration.

I don't know if this is the part of your code that is the bottleneck or not, you'll have to profile to know that, but this seemed like an easy improvement.

**EDIT**

I posted too soon. Your problem is in the `GetCellAtXY` function. You loop through (on average) half the cells to find your neighbor. And you do this 8 times for each cell, during each iteration!

Instead, create a cell object that directly points at its 8 neighbors, for example with:

```
struct Cell
{
  int x, y; // Cell X, Y coordiantes
  bool IsAlive; // Cell life state
  std::array<Cell*,8> neighbors;
}
```

Then you go through the loop to find the neighbors once (or you populate them as you create them, which is probably better). Note that when you set `A.neighbor[left]=&B`, then you also set `B.neighbor[right]=&A`.

I'm sure you'll get suggestions to do this without pointers, that using pointers is not proper C++. But I like pointers.

There are many alternatives: a 2D grid of cells, where you know the index of each neighbor by computation, a std::map where you index a cell by the hash of the coordinates, etc.

**EDIT**

Here is one way you could index neighbors. This is not necessarily the less verbose method, but it gets the ideas across:

```
struct FieldSize {
  int x, y;
}
FieldSize fieldSize{ 40, 20 };

struct Cell {
  int x, y; // Cell X, Y coordiantes
  bool IsAlive; // Cell life state
  // ...
  bool HasLeftNeighbor() {
    return x != 0;
  }
  bool HasRightNeighbor() {
    return x != fieldSize.x-1;
  }
  bool HasTopNeighbor() {
    return y != 0;
  }
  bool HasTopLeftNeighbor() {
    return HasLeftNeighbor() && HasTopNeighbor();
  }
  // ... etc.
  int GetLeftNeighbor() {
    return (x-1) + y * fieldSize.x;
  }
  int GetTopNeighbor() {
    return x + (y-1) * fieldSize.x;
  }
  int GetTopLeftNeighbor() {
    return (x-1) + (y-1) * fieldSize.x;
  }
  // ... etc.
}
```

Then in GetAdjacentCellCount:

```
if (HasLeftNeighbor() && map[GetLeftNeighbor()].IsAlive)
  aliveCount++;
// etc.
```

Again, this is very verbose, and can easily be made more compact and probably also more efficient, but I wanted to highlight the logic for you.

Comment: Hey thanks that helped quite a bit, but there is still performance issues. Your code sped up the iterations a good bit.

Comment: Cris! This is ironic, I wanted to implement a neighbors array into my struct, but I didn't know how to go about implementing it in general.

Comment: I'm used to dealing with images, so I'd approach it defining cells within an array (or `std::vector`) such that `cells(x+width*y)` is the cell at position (x,y), with x and y integers, and `width` the number of cells horizontally in the grid.

Comment: Then you can directly find your neighbors: if you're cell `I`, the left neighbor is at `I-1`, the right one at `I+1`, to the bottom at `I+width`, etc. You only need to take care of not looking for cells outside the bounds of your grid.

Comment: I understand the logic, yet I haven't gotten into graphical rendering yet, that's why I use GotoXY to do my draw calls. I wonder if I cant somehow get your neighbor array to work in my struct.

Comment: Could you explain the population of neighbors code a bit more in depth, I understand the concept, yet I can't really imagine it in my head.

Comment: @AlexJevdokimovSlyJellyBean I've updated the answer again. The neighbor array is more concept makes more sense if you want generic layouts, with arbitrary number of neighbors for each cell, but a fixed, rectangular grid of cells is the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Funny, to me the "natural" data structure of a game of life appears to be a 2 dimensional array; accessing a cell at a given coordinate is then trivial. Granted, that implies a fixed size universe.